# Stellar offer fulfilment process in orderbook. Are partial bids accepted by Stellar?

Tags: transactions, manageofferoperation

How does Stellar network does the order matching on orderbook for sell offers and does Stellar accept partial bid for order fulfillment? eg I want to sell 100 units of asset A. If I get bids from different buyers for different number of units lets say three bids for 25 units of A each. Can the offer be partially fulfilled by selling 25 number of units to three bidders totalling 75 units or one bidder has to bid for all 100 units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, orders can be partially fulfilled. The minimum tradable amount is **0.0000001**.